Unable to run --format-options for @cucumber/pretty-formatter
I am trying to run @cucumber-pretty formatter with my TypeScript Playwright project. But I get an error as the system cannot find the file specific. And I am trying to change the default theme settings because the whole console is writing white text which is not readable.
I have written this code in my package.json:
"scripts": {
    "parabank": "cucumber-js -f @cucumber/pretty-formatter --tags @Regression --config=config/cucumber.js --format-options '{'theme': <THEME_JSON>}'"
  }

I have tried to debug it multiple times but it doesn't work for a reason.
This is my cucumber.js file:
const { DEFAULT_THEME } = require('@cucumber/pretty-formatter')

module.exports = {

        default: {
            compilerOptions: {
                esModuleInterop: true,
                resolveJsonModule: true
            },
            formatOptions: {
                snippetInterface: "async-await",
                theme: {
                    ...DEFAULT_THEME,
                    'step text': 'red',
                    'step keyword': 'bold',
                    'scenario name': ['blue', 'bold']
                }
            },
            paths: [
                "src/test/features/"
                
            ],
            dryRun: false,
            require: [
                "src/test/steps/*.ts",
                "src/test/hooks/hooks.ts"
            ],
            requireModule: [
                "ts-node/register"
            ],
            format: [
                "html:cucumber-report.html"
            ]
        }
    
}

And the command I am trying to run with my package.json is:
"parabank": "cucumber-js -f @cucumber/pretty-formatter --tags @Regression --config=config/cucumber.js --format-options '{'theme': <THEME_JSON>}'"

Which should run with
"npm run parabank"

And THEME_JSON.json file contains:
{
    "name": "theme",
    "feature keyword": ["magenta", "bold"],
    "scenario keyword": ["red"]
}

Link to cucumber-pretty: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cucumber/pretty-formatter
Any help would be appericated, thanks in advance.
